# How to use I2S in ESP boards?

Tags: esp32

I have researched this a lot, but haven't found anything on which I can trust.
I want to use a particular ESP board to play audio. To play audio, I2S support is required. But, I know that not every ESP board break out the I2S pins from the chip. According to me, buying an ESP32 only to use the I2S would be a waste of money. So, my question is, if I just want to use I2S, which board is would be suitable? Please provide some references if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Few months ago I tested successfully I2S with [this library](https://github.com/earlephilhower/ESP8266Audio), I used the default pins:

```
bck_io_num = 26  
ws_io_num = 25  
data_out_num = 22
```

which are available on many boards such as Lolin D32.

Comment: Can we use any pin for the I2S?

Comment: I don't think so, those pins should be internally wired to the I2S peripheral (but I'm not sure)

Comment: You have to use the dedicated I2S pins.